# « Casser sa langue sur » et « Ça roule commodément sur la langue »

Tags: locutions, néerlandais

J’essaie de traduire deux locutions néerlandaises qui sont étroitement liées. ( Si vous pensez que cette question doit être divisée en deux quand-même alors vous pouvez le dire )

En néerlandais on peut dire qu’un mot *roule commodément sur la langue* au lieu de « ce mot se prononce aisément. » Cette tournure n’est pas forcément en rapport avec le « r » comme on le prononce en Espagne.

On peut aussi dire qu’on *casse sa langue sur quelque chose* quand la prononciation semble être vraiment coriace. Je connais la tournure « buter / trébucher sur des mots » mais ça peut aussi vouloir dire que quelqu’un parle mal, alors que la traduction que je souhaite doit avoir trait à ce que l’on essaie de prononcer.

Y-a-t-il des locutions françaises qui sont apparentées à celles que je donne ici ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pour une traduction littéraire ou technique :

> "Les mots roulent commodément sur la langue" : *la diction est fluide*,
>
> "On se casse la langue sur quelque chose" : *c'est imprononçable. Tu accroches sur ce mot (ou sur cette phrase)*.

En argot pour "... casser ..." :

> Ça s'bouscule aux portillons (surtout chez les bègues).
>
>  Remets les choses dans l'ordre.
>
>  Pourquoi tu bloques (*ou :* Pourquoi tu te prends les pieds dans le tapis) sur ce mot.

et pour "... rouler ..." :

> Dire ce texte, c'est du velours. (entendu chez les comédiens)